I would like to bring different image sizes to match the screen size
Below is the code I'm currently using.
<section className='relative h-screen w-full'>
      <div className='absolute z-10 h-full w-full bg-apply-background-gradient' />
      <Image
        className='object-cover'
        src='/webp/apply/top-banner-desktop.webp'
        alt='apply-top-banner'
        fill={true}
      />
      <div className='relative z-20 flex flex-col items-center gap-8 xl:pt-[360px]'>
        <h1 className='md:text-text-heading-2 xl:text-text-heading-1'>title</h1>
        <span className='text-text-title-2'>sub title</span>
      </div>
    </section>

but other banners should be visible on mobile.
️public
   webp
     apply
       top-banner-desktop.wepb
       top-banner-mobile.wepb

I've tried using srcSet, but it doesn't support it.
Can you recommend me what to do?
try

I tried using srcSet.
I tried using objectPosition. the design of desktop and mobile is not much different, but the object position is difficult to adjust to left 10% bottom 20%, so I prepared another file.

my thought
I also think about using the srcSet of the default image tag but I want to optimize it
wish
I want to show other images depending on the screen
